# WEBVR and threejs, how can I check whether the user is in VR mode or not?

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality, webvr

All the examples and tutorials on the threejs site and elsewhere offer this line:

```
document.body.appendChild( WEBVR.createButton( renderer ) );
```

Which adds a nice little button to enter VR mode. But there doesn't seem to be any way to detect whether or not the user has pressed it and entered VR mode or not. And there doesn't seem to be any way to enter VR mode besides using that button. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following line of code to check if the XR device has an active session.

```
renderer.xr.isPresenting()
```

Comment: Thankyou, that works. Is there a way to check when the user enters VR mode?(listen for an event), or can I explicitly call enterVR() or something and use my own button? I cannot find any documentation for renderer.vr...

Comment: @korrbit (and future readers) VRButton.js appears quite closed off, but if you make your own copy there are several places in that file where you can detect when a new XR session is started (reminder: take care to prevent your copy from being overwritten if you update three.js automatically [e.g., place it outside repository], and likewise be aware if necessary changes are made that you need to incorporate into yours).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help someone who use `react-three/fiber`,

```
import { useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";

const { gl } = useThree();

gl.xr.isPresenting
```